# Trigger de una vista a una tabla en SQLServer

Tags: sql-server

Estoy intentando crear un trigger que cuando exista un id de una tabla sea igual al valor de una fila en una vista, entonces el trigger se ejecute y tome el valor almacenado en la vista y concatene el valor de otra tabla y lo actualice, dejo una imagen de referencia.

[Ejemplo tablas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMffC.png)

La tabla vw_acta obtiene el valor de otra tabla que esta relacionada con t_carpeta, idCarpeta es el id de t_carpeta, t_carpeta es la principal, por lo tanto si id t_carpeta no existe, no existira relacion en las demas tablas o vista.
Puede existir una fila en t_carpeta sin relacion en vw_acta (posiblemente no exista un valor de donde se obtiene) pero nunca existira una fila en vw_vista si no existe en t_carpeta.

He intentado realizar un trigger que, segun el ejemplo de la imagen anterior, cuando se haga el insert en t_documento ese aparece en la vista vw_acta, es el codigo siguiente:

`CREATE TRIGGER trg_vw_acta ON dbo.vw_acta AFTER INSERT, UPDATE AS BEGIN UPDATE t SET t.nom_expediente = CONCAT(t.nom_expediente, ' ', i.valor) FROM exetera.dbo.t_carpeta t INNER JOIN inserted i ON t.id = i.id_carpeta END`

Pero SQLServer me arroja el error:

Mensaje 8197, nivel 16, estado 6, procedimiento trg_vw_actas_concat, línea 1 [línea de inicio de lote 0]
The object 'dbo.vw_acta' does not exist or is invalid for this operation.

Hora de finalización: 2023-04-13T10:03:48.9167340-05:00

Comment: estás seguro que `dbo.vw_Acta` es una tabla y no una vista?

Comment: dbo.vw_Acta es una vista entre t_carpeta y t_documento.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que las vistas no aceptan triggers del tipo `AFTER`, tendrías que hacer un trigger `INSTEAD OF` que  replique la funcionalidad en las tablas afectadas y después ejecute el proceso que quieres realizar.

Dejo un ejemplo con la estructura de tablas según lo entendí. Es buena práctica que compartas la estructura de tablas como código para que no tengamos que gastar tiempo en replicarlo y poder probar.

```
CREATE TABLE t_carpeta(
    id              int IDENTITY,
    nom_expediente  varchar(10),
    caja            int,
    carpeta         int
);
CREATE TABLE t_documento(
    id              int IDENTITY,
    id_carpeta      int,
    valor           varchar(10)
);
GO
CREATE VIEW vw_acta
AS
SELECT id_carpeta,
        valor
FROM t_documento

GO

CREATE TRIGGER trg_vw_acta ON dbo.vw_acta 
INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE 
AS 
BEGIN 
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted)
        INSERT INTO t_documento(
            id_carpeta,
            valor
        )
        SELECT id_carpeta,
                valor
        FROM inserted
    ELSE
        UPDATE d SET
            valor = i.valor
        FROM t_documento d
        JOIN inserted i ON d.id_carpeta = i.id_carpeta


    UPDATE t SET 
        t.nom_expediente = CONCAT(t.nom_expediente, ' ', i.valor) 
    FROM dbo.t_carpeta t 
    INNER JOIN inserted i ON t.id = i.id_carpeta 
END
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, no compartí la estructura real debido a que es más compleja que la imagen que puse y para obtener el valor en vw_vista, hay 3 tablas más involucradas, lo hice de esa forma es debido a que con ese ejemplo pensé que si se podría, ya yo puedo replicarlo y adaptarlo a la realidad. Pero debido a que los triggers no se pueden crear en vista, se complican un poco mas las cosas, sin embargo, voy a analizar el codigo que compartiste y lo probare.